# Invalid Arithmetic Operator Inside Awk

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I'm trying to workaround bash's floating point arithmetic limitation via awk, but I'm encountering a syntax error which I'm having issues identifying.

```
declare -a mreal=()
for s in $(seq 0 $(( ${#mint_est[@]} - 1 )))
do
    mreal=( "${mreal[@]}" "$(echo ${mreal_est[$s]} | \
        awk -v int="${mint_est[$s]}" -v tot="$mtotal" \
        '{printf("%s", $1 + (1.0 - int/$1)*tot)}')" )
done
```

Here `mreal_est` and `mint_est`are arrays consisting of 4 floating point values each and `mtotal` is a variable set to a floating point value.  The syntax errors from awk are:

```
awk: {printf("%s", $1 + (1.0 - int/$1)*tot)}
awk:                              ^ syntax error
awk: {printf("%s", $1 + (1.0 - int/$1)*tot)}
awk:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: {printf("%s", $1 + (1.0 - int/$1)*tot)}
awk:                                       ^ syntax error
```

for each iteration through the loop.  I am trying to get the array `mreal` populated with floating point values based upon the arithmetic defined in awk's `printf` statement.  Any ideas how this might be corrected?

Comment: How what might be corrected? Is the script doing something undesirable and, if so, what? Post some small sample input and expected output.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, I get three syntax errors for each iteration in the loop.  I'll edit the question to highlight the errors.  I am expecting that the `mreal` array gets populated with 4 floating point values based on the arithmetic defined in awk's `printf` statement.

Comment: `awk` is not particularly stellar at floating point, either, although it has at least some capabilities, which puts it a bit ahead of `bash` in that arena. You might want to look into `bc` instead...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int()` is an awk function, you can't use `int` as a variable name:

```
$ gawk -v int=7 'BEGIN{print int}'
gawk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{print int}
gawk: cmd. line:1:                ^ parse error

$ gawk -v xint=7 'BEGIN{print xint}'
7
```

Comment: That was it--my mistake.  Thanks for highlighting this error for me.